# How to cancel update in oracle.?

Tags: oracle

How can i cancel update in oracle.

For example my query is:

**STEP 1:**

```
UPDATE CUSTOMER SET Name='Sesuraj',Age='23',Gender='Male';
```

**My output is:**

```
Name: Sesuraj, Age: 23, Gender: Male
```

**STEP 2:**
Now i am going to update my table again with following query:

```
UPDATE CUSTOMER SET Name='Sesuraj',Age='23',Gender='Male';
```

**My output is:**

```
Name: Sesuraj, Age: 23, Gender: Male
```

So STEP 1 = STEP 2

When ever STEP 1 =STEP 2 I want to avoid update, else i want to update my table.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Knowing the reason will help us to suggest an acceptable solution.

Comment: @Polppan Oracle version 10g

Comment: @Sesuraj Would like to make sure one thing, when it is matched you would want to update and if doesn't match, then do a insert. Normally when STEP1 = STEP2 then why do want to do this? As pointed out by RaviH, describe the problem you are having, there bu others would be able to provide better solutions.

Comment: @Polppan i have a table in oracle. it contains three filed Name, Old_Date and New_Date. Name= Sesuraj, Old_Date= 31/12/13 New_Date= 31/12/14. Now i want to update my table. When ever New_Date is changed Previous New_Date will be stored into old_Date automatically. Old_Date: 31/12/14, New_Date= 31/12/15. So, old=new. update customers set name='guru', old_date=new_date, new_date='31/12/15'. Its working. Now i have to restrict updation if new_date doesn't changed.

Comment: @Sesuraj So you would want to check `new_date` is equal to `old_date` and if it is same, then do not update. If it is not equal update `name` and `old_date` correct?

Comment: @Polppan yeah correct :)

Comment: @Sesuraj I have modified my answer, kindly have a look and see whether this is suffice.

Comment: You want to update all customers stored in `customers` table or there are some condition to match required customer? E.g. if your have 2 records in table: `{old_date='01/01/01', Name='OldGuru-1'}` and `{old_date='02/02/02', Name='OldGuru-2'}` both must be updated with your example `update customers set name='guru', old_date=new_date, new_date='31/12/15'` ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, try the following approach

```
DECLARE
    v_count  NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT  COUNT (*)
      INTO  v_count
      FROM  customer
     WHERE  old_date = '<new_date>';

    IF (v_count) < 1
    THEN
        UPDATE  customer
            SET name = 'Abc',
                    old_date = '<new_date>',
                    new_date = '15-Dec-2012';
    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

quite easy

```
UPDATE CUSTOMER
SET Name = 'Sesuraj',
    Age = '23',
    Gender = 'Male'
WHERE Name != 'Sesuraj',
   OR Age != '23',
   OR Gender != 'Male';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [MERGE statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606). With this statement, you can INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE into one statement, depending on the data already in the table.

```
    MERGE INTO CUSTOMERS t
    USING
    (SELECT 'Sesuraj' AS name, 23 AS age, 'Male' AS gender FROM DUAL) s
    ON
    (s.name=t.name AND s.age=t.age AND s.gender=t.gender)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (t.name, t.age, t.gender)
    VALUES (s.name, s.age, s.gender)
    ;
```

In the `ON` clause you describe which data should be used to find a pre-existing row in the table. In this case the row must fully match. If you want to match only on the name, then you can use `ON (s.name=t.name)`.

You can find [a live fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1ed61/8).